# How to initialise an array of empty arrays in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

My aim is to have an array of empty arrays in swift. Something like this:

```
[[][][][][]]
```

They are all of type Game. This is my attempt:

```
 let numberOfDays = 5
 var gamesCache: [[Game]] = [](count: numberOfDays, repeatedValue: [])
```

It comes up with the error. Cannot call value of non function type '[Any]'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this way.

```
let numberOfDays = 5
var gamesCache = [[Game]](count: numberOfDays, repeatedValue: [])
```

Comment: Swift 5: [[Game]](repeating: [], count: numberOfDays)